# Changing the number of threads in TensorFlow on Cifar10

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

Whenever I run the cifar10_eval.py, in creates 32 threads as following:

**I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 32**

I think this number of threads is the number of threads running on CPUs, but when I check the usage, only 400-500% of CPUs are used. Is there anyway to change this number of threads?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To configure this value, you can pass a `tf.ConfigProto` argument when constructing the [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/Session):

```
NUM_THREADS = …
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_THREADS))
```

Comment: The threads are standard pthreads that operate a thread pool, created by the C++ code in [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc).

Comment: @mrry This is useful. Can you please answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774250/run-syntaxnet-on-multiple-cores)

Comment: it's safe to include also the inter_op_parallelism_threads option as `session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1))`