# Run multiple tensorflow ops with shared memory in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to run multiple instances of an op which depend on a shared kernel (a tensorflow variable) `K`, in parallel.

From the tensorflow FAQ:

> The Session API allows multiple concurrent steps (i.e. calls to tf.Session.run in parallel. This enables the runtime to get higher throughput, if a single step does not use all of the resources in your computer.

My code looks similar to this:

```
def some_op(K):
    # Do some processing on shared K
    return some_value

K = tf.random_uniform([kernel_size, kernel_size], 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)

op_ = some_op(K)    

op_list = []
for i in range(n_experiments):
    op_list.append(op_)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    vals = sess.run(op_list)
    print vals
```

I am getting no speedup at all. The runtimes are as:

- `n_experiments`, runtime(s)
- 1             , 2.35
- 5             , 10.32
- 10            , 24.58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `op_list` contains `n_experiments` copies of the same `tf.Tensor`. If that is the case, calling `sess.run(op_list)` will execute the op once, then make `n_experiments` copies of the result. If you want to invoke multiple instances of `some_op(K)` in parallel, you should rewrite the code as follows:

```
op_list = []
for i in range(n_experiments):
  op_list.append(some_op(K))
```

Note that increasing `n_experiments` is likely to increase the execution time, because you're issuing more work to the same set of resources. If you want to increase the potential parallelism, you can use `tf.ConfigProto`  when creating your session, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34390517/3574081).